# StreamReader reading from Text file

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm running `StreamReader` over a text file and storing the data into an `ArrayList`. The data is separated by "," and it stores appointment dates and times. Some patients have only been seen twice so I have to add no data into the text file but still add the "," to insure the `StreamReader` moves over it.

However when it gets to the `Patient` that only has two visits it stops reading the file and just stores the data up to that point. I have a `try`/`catch` error handling which tells me when it stops reading the file.

eg;

```
1, Name,DOB,12/12/2015,13/12/2015,,,,
2, Name,DOB,11/11/2015,,,,
```

It reads all the patients which had the full 5 visits however the ones with no data between the "," it stops reading.

My code of reading it, is as follows;

```
public static void LoadPatient(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename); //System IO for StreamReader
        while (!file.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = file.ReadLine();
            string[] fields = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());
            int PID = int.Parse(fields[0]);
            string pName = fields[1];
            string NIN = fields[2];
            DateTime pDOB = DateTime.Parse(fields[3]);
            string pGender = fields[4];
            DateTime Visit1 = DateTime.Parse(fields[5]);
            int Duration1 = int.Parse(fields[6]);

            DateTime Visit2 = DateTime.Parse(fields[7]);
            int Duration2 = int.Parse(fields[8]);
            DateTime Visit3 = DateTime.Parse(fields[9]);
            int Duration3 = int.Parse(fields[10]);
            DateTime Visit4 = DateTime.Parse(fields[11]);
            int Duration4 = int.Parse(fields[12]);
            DateTime Visit5 = DateTime.Parse(fields[13]);
            int Duration5 = int.Parse(fields[14]);
            Patient p = new Patient();

            p.ID = PID;
            p.Name = pName;
            p.DOB = pDOB;
            p.Gender = pGender;
            p.NIN = NIN;
            p.Visit1 = Visit1;
            p.Duration1 = Duration1;
            p.Visit2 = Visit2;
            p.Duration2 = Duration2;
            p.Visit3 = Visit3;
            p.Duration3 = Duration3;
            p.Visit4 = Visit4;
            p.Duration4 = Duration4;
            p.Visit5 = Visit5;
            p.Duration5 = Duration5;
            patientList.Add(p);

        }
        file.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error loading Data file");
    }
}
```

Comment: probably the nothing between the "," can be parsed neither to integer nor datetime

Comment: Would you suggest not converting them until after they are read into the arraylist

Comment: Do not convert them if they are empty

Comment: You could check their length for instance

Comment: It is stopping because fields doesn't contain 15 items (0 to 14).  So you must check in your code that you have a count of 15 after you split the input.  So add an if statement before each visit testing the count of field to determine the number of visits.

Comment: _"I have to add no data into the text file but still add the ",""_ -- yes, that's one way to address it. So why haven't you? The text you show here has four empty fields at the end of each line, regardless of the number of non-empty fields in a line. If you want to use the code you have, you need to make sure you pad the line with enough commas to make 15 fields. You also haven't provided a good [mcve] with a complete example of the input.

Comment: This is one of the lines from my text file and it has been separated by "," as you will see however it is still stopping once it gets to this part strangely ;

5,Bob Down,PO113322B,11/04/1985,Male,25/03/2016,40,22/04/2016,40,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

I would not say it is exactly "stopping", it is throwing an exception. You have a simple case of not checking your indexes. You need to ensure a value at all indexes exist and that value can be parsed to the data type you want. You can use `ElementAtOrDefault()` on your array to obtain a `null` instead of an index out of range exception. You can use `TryParse` to convert without throwing invalid cast exceptions.

Replace your `while` loop with:

```
 while (!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = file.ReadLine();
        string[] fields = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());

        Patient p = new Patient();

        int id = 0;
        DateTime dob = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime visit1 = DateTime.MinValue;
        int duration1 = 0;
        //... etc. for each visit 2, 3, 4 and 5

        int.TryParse(fields.ElementAtOrDefault(0), out id);
        p.Name = fields.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
        p.NIN = fields.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
        DateTime.TryParse(fields.ElementAtOrDefault(3), out dob);            
        p.Gender = fields.ElementAtOrDefault(4);
        DateTime.TryParse(fields.ElementAtOrDefault(5), out visit1);
        int.TryParse(fields.ElementAtOrDefault(6), out duration1);

        //... etc. for each visit 2, 3, 4 and 5

        p.ID = id;
        p.DOB = dob;
        p.Visit1 = visit1;
        p.Duration1 = duration1;
        //... etc. for each visit 2, 3, 4 and 5

        patientList.Add(p);
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply..I will feedback when I'm home to try

Comment: Ive input the code you provided however I have a few errors at the end of each line...Stating "A property or indexer may not be used as an out or reference parameter"

Comment: I should have noticed that. You will need to create intermediate variables instead of assigning directly to your Patient properties.

Comment: after updating with the amended code it now states "The name 'fields' does not exist in the current context ". Thanks again for your help.